# How to give permission to jenkins for writing the file after downloading from TFS?

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I am able to download the code from TFS successfully, but all the file has "Read only" access. How to give permission to jenkins to download files without "Read only" access so that I can modify the required file at the time of building?

Comment: Can you add a bit more context. 
* What OS is the server running
* Who owns the file

Comment: Why the files got from TFS  are all "Read only" ? How did you achieve this operation? Moreover, are you using a server workspace in TFS?